# Connect FTPS via Apache.Camel Read timed out

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I need to consume file from ftps via camel(ServiceMix), so I launched local FTPS server with FileZilla. Connection with this server via FileZilla Client works great, but using camel in karaf logs I get IOException(shortcut StackTrace below). 
Camel Version 2.16.4

My in xml DSL(blueprint) code:

```
<from uri="ftps://127.0.0.1:990/newFold/?username=test&amp;password=12345&amp;binary=true&amp;download=true&amp;passiveMode=true"/>
```

In FileZilla logs:
(000396)07.05.2018 16:27:00 - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> Connected on port 990, sending welcome message...

And then connection timeout

StackTrace:

2018-05-07 16:13:50,357 | WARN  | mix-6.1.3/deploy | FtpConsumer                      | 151 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.4 | Error auto creating directory: newFold/ due File operation failed:  Timed out waiting for initial connect reply. Code: 0. This exception is ignored.
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed:  Timed out waiting for initial connect reply. Code: 0

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for initial connect reply

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Comment: Have you consider updating camel version? according to official website Camel versions 2.18.x and older are no longer actively developed.

Comment: @Rcordoval My whole company uses version 2.16.4, this is not in my power :)

Comment: Can you check whether an SSL handshake error occurred on adding [`-Djavax.net.debug=all`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) as system argument to your application invocation? Maybe the connection is refused due to some insecure ciphers being used. You can also enable Camel's TRACE log to gain more insight what was causing the issue inside the FTPConsumer

Comment: May you try this please? <from uri="ftps://test@127.0.0.1:990/newFold?password=12345&amp;
          binary=true&amp;
          download=true&amp;
          throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&amp;
          soTimeout=300000&amp;
          timeout=300000&amp;
          passiveMode=true"/>

Comment: @Rcordoval Sorry, for late answer, with this options bundle works same, initial connection to ftps timed out.